# TypeScript: How to handle polymorphic return type in generic function parameter?

Tags: typescript, generics, polymorphism

Please reference the TypeScript code snippet below.  Why do the commented lines fail?  How do I specify the HandlerFunction type so that returns of the subclass type are allowed?

(I realize in the generated JS code the types are removed, and the objects are not sliced at runtime, but I'd like to keep the TypeScript code hints intact for the subclasses.)

Here's a link to the below code in the TypeScript playground:  [TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3ggL4CwAUOSmhgIIDKAriAjgB4Q4B2AJhtmHnzkECYAC4EkKAEtOAcwQBeBAHIVAbnKkKZKuiyNmbDjz64CwhCAmcGAWxA4oShAAZNZbZQD2nSAjsATwAxBk5YFwAKAAtgHmQnMQAJOO4EqFDwiGlfAEoxADdvaW4lAD4LMhFYXzBvBIA6ZG85SJVZAJCw2AAaBDlvRFj4xNU%204bSnXI8iDx8-RDkcCBoo-PomcoROHAB3BA2QSOnyef8liEw1sUxDLZ3926ZjuZ0AejeEYOBpZDAGgHkCCBAAOeBSIwy3WyvhcAB4ACosdhcXhYXBlY5bBEeIKZWCRC40aYiD4IBF0ABMAGYACwAVgkNCgcnsXEQ3gAZghgWDVFjFBVDioENIMJxBqJ0NI5JxQAked4ECDgDA7MsnAguTzQXgVBDJlCsjlOCoGuTdaphaLxZLqDK5SAFRAlby9QizVbDCKxVKwA75XgXTzongagsYLIOdy3aoPX0QAxECoPUhvAxkKVHKKFnFssAOKVdtIINFRAhuNJOZynOzJExY9rw1Ifpxk-wcGbyHjuoTlpgSQgyRSaQymSy2W2tTHLSoBRUniAfbbEPbZYHFcrVcB1RxnNrY-rUul8TDTeaEbPF8vtnbpeunUHXbOPeaVNebX6A4-N6Ww7VoFbaMdT5FMVATJM4xFGoMyzPBZEgPNpALHAixLMtgArKsaygOswAbS0mwAyMp3fXAu3eT4AHVvCgABrf5ATID5YwNE9oRNeEkWMVEzAETFci2DsPDJHtwj7FYTmYz4xIJC4Bw8IA)

```
abstract class Base { }

class ASub extends Base {
  a: string = '';
}

class BSub extends Base {
  b: number = 0;
}

const myFunc = (handler:HandlerFunction):void => {
  console.log('in myFunc, got handler: ', handler);
};

const getA = ():ASub => new ASub();

const getB = ():BSub => new BSub();


// Fails... Note return type of HandlerFunction is 'T':
// type HandlerFunction = <T extends Base>() => T;
// myFunc(getA);  // TS2345: Argument of type '() => ASub' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HandlerFunction'. Type 'ASub' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'ASub' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.
// myFunc(getB);  // TS2345: Argument of type '() => BSub' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HandlerFunction'. Type 'BSub' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'BSub' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Base'.

// Works... Note return type of HandlerFunction is 'Base':
type HandlerFunction = <T extends Base>() => Base;
myFunc(getA);
myFunc(getB);
```

Comment: Why not just `type HandlerFunction = () => Base` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NDzGlW)?  That allows return types of `ASub` and `BSub` just fine.  Generics aren't helping you here.  Your generic `HandlerFunction` type says "this is a function that takes no input and returns whatever subtype of `Base` the *caller* wants", which is essentially impossible to implement safely. Your `getA` (or `getB`) function certainly doesn't implement that, since it returns `ASub` (or `BSub`) no matter what the caller wants.  I'm happy to answer this but I can't tell if you have a use case that needs generics.

Comment: Note: if you do have a use case where the return type being narrower than `Base` matters, please show it with a [mre].  Right now the `myFunc` consumer doesn't even call `handler`, so it's not clear why anyone anywhere cares what the return type is.  Depending on your use case, you might want to make `myFunc` generic in `T extends () => Base`, but I'd just be guessing without an example that demonstrates the need.

Comment: @jcalz - Thanks.  You're right; I was over-thinking the need for the generic.  While the code above was a greatly simplified example just to encapsulate the error I was seeing, the actual app code didn't need the generic, either.  If you'd like, submit your response above as the answer to the question, and I'll mark it as such so you get the reputation bump.